# OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this model, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, stable-diffusion

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py", line 403, in get_feature_extractor_dict
resolved_feature_extractor_file = cached_path(
File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 282, in cached_path
output_path = get_from_cache(
File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 545, in get_from_cache
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_features_extraction.py", line 14, in 
from pnp_utils import check_safety
File "/data1/wz/research/plug-and-play-main/pnp_utils.py", line 14, in 
safety_feature_extractor = AutoFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(safety_model_id)
File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/feature_extraction_auto.py", line 270, in from_pretrained
config_dict, _ = FeatureExtractionMixin.get_feature_extractor_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusion/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py", line 436, in get_feature_extractor_dict
raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this model, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like CompVis/stable-diffusion-safety-checker is not the path to a directory containing a preprocessor_config.json file.
Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.

i dont know how to solve this problem